# Compare photos with Perceptual_hashing using huawei-mlkit to find photos that show the same person?

Tags: android, machine-learning, computer-vision, image-recognition, huawei-mobile-services

Is it possible to use [huawei's mlkit](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/hms/huawei-mlkit) to calculate
[perceptual hashes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceptual_hashing) of human faces and are there examples how to implemnt this?

mlkit is capable of finding eys/nose/mouth/ears of a face in images so it should be possible to calculate some "perceptual_hash" of it.

Comment: Without knowing this lib (and also not doing much ML): I only see face detection / landmark-detection (locating eyes, nose and so one) in the docs and detection != recognition (and embedding). In your case, you are *probably* (might depend on some scale if pairwise recognition is a valid alternative) even looking for face-embedding: a mapping of some face onto some metric-space.  I would not expect general-purpose perceptual-hashing to work on this task. Even when restricted to the face-detection bounding-box. If the docs are not missing out stuff, i don't think this lib will make you happy.

Comment: From relativ positions and size of eys/nose/mouth/ears/.. relative to each other it may be possible to calculate a kind of fingerprint that may usefull for face recognitions

Comment: Yes, but there might be a reason nobody is doing it like that ;-) Everything is possible, but not everything performs well. Just google face-embedding / facenet to get some initial pointer (there might be newer things though).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

Please kindly refer to ML Kit [Face Vertification](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/faceverification-0000001071919926). It recognizes and extracts key features of the face in the template, compares the features with those of the face in the input image, and then determines whether the two faces belong to the same person based on their similarity.

---

[ML Kit](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/service-introduction-0000001050040017?ha_source=hms1) face detection service can detect the face contour, recognize facial features, and determine facial expressions for a person. But it cannot recognize faces, so it cannot compare photos to find whether they are of the same person.

---

According to HUAWEI HiAI Engine documentation, the capability of [Facial Comparison](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/hiai-Guides/facial-comparison-introduction-0000001053859748?ha_source=hms1) can identify and extract facial features, perform comparison on faces, and provide scores to determine whether the objects are the same person.